# How to add the SeekBar for resize the web-view text size Android?

Tags: android-webview, seekbar

```
SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar)root.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        webview.getSettings().setTextZoom(progress);
    webview.loadData(abst.getAbstract_detail(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What values are being set by progress? Is it in the range 0-100? On which platform version of Android is this a problem?

Comment: yes progress range is 0 to 100. and version is 4.1.2